# Eclipse makes wrong choice of JAR as project dependency when class presents in more than one library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, import

I work on a big Java application and I'm having problem compiling it under Eclipse Kepler:

- the application is based on Maven 3.1.0 and successfully compiles there
- I generate Eclipse configuration (project files) using mvn eclipse:eclipse

The problem is that certain classes present in more than one JAR (e.g. imagine a class Http and two versions of this class where newer has more methods) and Eclipse makes a wrong choice of the depending class (older one) for particular project which makes it not compilable.

I tried to move Jars up/down in the project dependencies and it helps in certain situations, however, it means that I'm changing configuration changed by Maven.

Is it possible to configure Eclipse so that is "smarter"? Is it caused by Maven (POM files, a bug in Maven's eclipse plugin, ...) although maven compiles the project without any problems? Any other suggestion?

Comment: specifying version in imports in `pom.xml`, i would suggest that

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! Do you mean that I should specify the version of the dependency and it will help Eclipse to make the right choice?

Comment: no i think the 1 i suggested is for runtime not compile time! but i did not get the thing, suppose there are 3 versions of a jar, the latest one will have all the classes and methods right, and don't tell me your code still uses deprecated ones!!

Comment: No deprecated methods are used. It relates to common classes that certain Jars have in it like HTTP related interfaces, QName, etc.

Comment: well its all on you i think, you import the class and it will refer the same, even if you use auto import it will ask you if there are same classes available from different packages!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use mvn eclipse:eclipse.  The official way today is to use the m2e plugin (which is much smarter) with File->Import->Existing Maven projects.

When you open a pom.xml file you can see the dependency hierarchy and why a given jar was chosen.

(Note that most but not all standard distributions of the latest Eclipse contains m2e.  If your do not you can download it from the marketplace, but it may be easier to download a distribution that has it).